# Failed to yum update - Error importing repomd.xml for appistry: Damaged repomd.xml file

Tags: proxy, yum

I was trying to perform `yum update` and received the error below:

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                      | 8.5 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirror.newmediaexpress.com
 * epel: epel.dionipe.id
 * extras: mirror.newmediaexpress.com
 * updates: mirror.newmediaexpress.com
appistry                                                                                           |  80 kB     00:00 ... 
http://repo.appistry.com/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for appistry: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: appistry. Please verify its path and try again
```

I have tried `yum clean all` followed by `yum update` as suggested by some sites but it does not work. Some people solved it by adding proxy to `/etc/yum.conf`. My problem is, I don't even see the proxy of the server. Both `echo $http_proxy` and `echo $https_proxy` show no output.

Is it possible to solve this issue without proxy? Or is there a way to bypass the proxy? Or do I have to create a proxy? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try if you can wget/curl the repo url: http://repo.appistry.com/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
this would confirm the connectivity from your host